# Is mapping array elements to perfect hash indexes NP Complete?

Tags: algorithm, computation-theory, np

Assuming I have a set of integers that can range from 0 to INT64MAX, but I know the set in its entirety so I can generate a perfect hash.

If I want to use these hashes as array indices, I need to modulus with the size of the array I want to store this in.

This brings a problem where I want to find a non-colliding set for my hashes that map to integers such that minimal array size is needed and I still have no collisions.

Is this NP complete? It "feels" NP Complete.

Comment: Let me rephrase this to see whether I got that: You want to find a function that maps a set of K integers from 0 to N (K<N) to the numbers from 0 to K without any collisions? Also, do you want to achieve this using just a single modulo operation? Or do you want to _select_ those K numbers such that they map perfectly using some given function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### No.

There exist algorithms that construct perfect hashes (even minimal perfect hashes) in linear time. See for example the [CMPH](http://cmph.sourceforge.net/) docs which list a couple of them.

Linear time means deterministic polynomial problem, thus the problem lies in `P`. P is contained in `NP`, but the problem certainly is not at least as hard as the hardest problems in `NP`, thus it is not in `NP-hard`.

`NP-complete` is defined as being in **both** `NP` and `NP-hard`. Therefore, it is not NP-complete.